# JS: Run function outside iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a website where you can press Ctrl+C (using shortcut.js library) and a text field appears, where you can type a command to go somewhere else, but the content of "somewhere else" is loaded inside an iframe.

The thing is that with some websites Ctrl+C still works, and with others it does not.
Is there a way to make the function always check the keyboard  even if the focus is on the iframe?

Comment: Events don't cross iframe borders, so I'd say the answer is no. Not sure if anything can be done in the capturing phase.

Comment: It's not possible simply because the user is not on your page now. He's on other's page now so you have absolutely no control over its content, and of course, event as well.